# Table Created With Convert From Textfile Has Gaps in Vertical Lines

Tags: color, text, tables, imagemagick

I did find a solution for the main problem: see the end of this question.

I have a text-file which contains:

```
┌────┬────┬────┬────┐
│ A♦ │ K♥ │ Q♠ │ J♣ │
└────┴────┴────┴────┘
```

I convert it with:

```
convert -interline-spacing 0 -size 250x100 -gravity center -fill black -font Liberation-Mono -density 96 -pointsize 12 caption:"$(<brokenLines.txt)" brokenLines.png
```

This works reasonably well and produces:

[image: Table with broken vertical lines]

But this has two problems:

1. There are gaps in the vertical lines.
2. I would like the diamond and heart to be red.

How would I implement this?

I found a solution for the first and main problem, use:

```
-interline-spacing -2
```

instead of:

```
-interline-spacing 0
```

Then I get (the above went OK on someone else's system):

[image: Table without broken vertical lines]

Comment: It seems to me like a general problem with how the border is created, rather than just the vertical lines. I can see gaps in the horizontal sections as well. The easy fix might be to just use a different font. I checked the font this site uses to display the text (Menlo) and then I used it to create a new image dropping out `-density` and [it looks just as solid as it does on this site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMVlM.png). It's not perfect, but it's pretty solid.

Comment: I just noticed the first font on this site is `Consolas` and `Menlo` is the second fallback. Thought I'd mention that to avoid confusion. Consolas looks better than your first image but not as good as Menlo.